# stop server side caching file (Centos 7, Apache)

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, cache, vps

I set up a server but I need to disable server caching temporary on my website to see my changes. I actually set up another website on my sub-domain so it would be better if I disable caching by `VirtualHost` configuration I mean just for this domain (this directory of my site's files).

I find some options on internet but it wasn't clear to me. any help?

Comment: you might try putting the `DocumentRoot` on it's own filesystem and then [mount with the `dax` option for direct access](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/dax.txt).

Comment: @Bratchley, sorry I didn't understand. what is that `dax`?

Comment: Mount option for ext4